# how to translate dependent drop down in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I am using angular translator in my app translation is working with the labels how to do add a translation to the dependent dropdown.Dropdown data is in the form of JSON how to write it in a config function

Controller

```
 .controller('vendorCtrl', function($scope,$translate) {

       $scope.Districts =[
   {
     'id': '1',
      'name': "Haveri",
      'Talukas': [{
         'id': '71',
         'dep': "Bydagi"
     }, {
         'id': '72',
         'dep': "Rannebennur"
     },
        { 'id': '73',
         'dep': "Hirrekerur"
     },{
         'id': '74',
         'dep': "Shiggaon"
     },
        { 'id': '75',
         'dep': "Hangal"

     },{ 'id': '76',
         'dep': "Savanur"
     }]
   }, 
           {
     'id': '8',
      'name': "Koppal",
      'Talukas': [{
         'id': '81',
         'dep': "Gangavathi"
     }, {
         'id': '82',
         'dep': "Kushtagi"
     },
        { 'id': '83',
         'dep': "Yelbarga"
     }]
   },    {
     'id': '9',
      'name': "Vijapur",
      'Talukas': [{
         'id': '91',
         'dep': "Indi"
     }, {
         'id': '92',
         'dep': "Muddebihal"
     },
        { 'id': '93',
         'dep': "Sindgi"
     } , {
         'id': '94',
         'dep': "BasavanBagewadi"
     }]
   }
   ];
```

Html

```
<select id="District" ng-model="selectedDistrict" ng-options="District.id as District.name for District  in Districts track by District.id">
        <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
<select id="Taluka" 
    ng-model="selectedTaluka" 
    ng-disabled="!selectedDistrict" 
    ng-model="selectedTaluka" 
    ng-options="Taluka.id as Taluka.dep for Taluka in ((Districts  | filter:{'id':selectedDistrict})[0].Talukas) track by Taluka.id">
        <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use angular-translate and try to translate the district names. Then you can use the translate pipe in ng-options. Try `ng-options="District.id as District.name | translate for District  in Districts track by District.id"`

Comment: Ya am using angular translator but the problem is with JSON data am not getting how to write JSON in controller